# Custom back icon in android toolbar using navigation component, bottomnavmenu

Tags: android, android-toolbar, bottomnavigationview, android-architecture-navigation

I want to use my own back icon in toolbar while using navigation component and bottom nav menu.

I have tried every possible solution but still I am displayed default back icon.

When I write

```
binding.toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back)
```

in onCreate MainActivity then that icon is displayed but when I navigate to next screen it uses default.

I added onDestinationListener

```
val destinationChangedListener =
        NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->

            when(destination.id){
                R.id.subCategoriesFragment -> {
                    // Nothing is working
                    supportActionBar?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
                    supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back)
                    binding.toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back)
                }
                else -> {
                    binding.toolbar.navigationIcon = null
                }
            }
        }
```

Still toolbar displays default icon.
[image: navigation vie bottom tab]

I am using google's Navigation extention which manages backstacks of all bottom menus.

Extension code is below.

```
/**
 * Manages the various graphs needed for a [BottomNavigationView].
 *
 * This sample is a workaround until the Navigation Component supports multiple back stacks.
 */
fun BottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(
    navGraphIds: List<Int>,
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    containerId: Int,
    intent: Intent
): LiveData<NavController> {

    // Map of tags
    val graphIdToTagMap = SparseArray<String>()
    // Result. Mutable live data with the selected controlled
    val selectedNavController = MutableLiveData<NavController>()

    var firstFragmentGraphId = 0

    // First create a NavHostFragment for each NavGraph ID
    navGraphIds.forEachIndexed { index, navGraphId ->
        val fragmentTag = getFragmentTag(index)

        // Find or create the Navigation host fragment
        val navHostFragment = obtainNavHostFragment(
            fragmentManager,
            fragmentTag,
            navGraphId,
            containerId
        )

        // Obtain its id
        val graphId = navHostFragment.navController.graph.id

        if (index == 0) {
            firstFragmentGraphId = graphId
        }

        // Save to the map
        graphIdToTagMap[graphId] = fragmentTag

        // Attach or detach nav host fragment depending on whether it's the selected item.
        if (this.selectedItemId == graphId) {
            // Update livedata with the selected graph
            selectedNavController.value = navHostFragment.navController
            attachNavHostFragment(fragmentManager, navHostFragment, index == 0)
        } else {
            detachNavHostFragment(fragmentManager, navHostFragment)
        }
    }

    // Now connect selecting an item with swapping Fragments
    var selectedItemTag = graphIdToTagMap[this.selectedItemId]
    val firstFragmentTag = graphIdToTagMap[firstFragmentGraphId]
    var isOnFirstFragment = selectedItemTag == firstFragmentTag

    // When a navigation item is selected
    setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(Intent(SELECTED_RESELETED_ITEM).apply {
            putExtra("item", item.itemId)
        })
        // Don't do anything if the state is state has already been saved.
        if (fragmentManager.isStateSaved) {
            false
        } else {
            val newlySelectedItemTag = graphIdToTagMap[item.itemId]
            if (selectedItemTag != newlySelectedItemTag) {
                // Pop everything above the first fragment (the "fixed start destination")
                fragmentManager.popBackStack(firstFragmentTag,
                    FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
                val selectedFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(newlySelectedItemTag)
                    as NavHostFragment

                // Exclude the first fragment tag because it's always in the back stack.
                if (firstFragmentTag != newlySelectedItemTag) {
                    // Commit a transaction that cleans the back stack and adds the first fragment
                    // to it, creating the fixed started destination.
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(
                            R.anim.nav_default_enter_anim,
                            R.anim.nav_default_exit_anim,
                            R.anim.nav_default_pop_enter_anim,
                            R.anim.nav_default_pop_exit_anim)
                        .attach(selectedFragment)
                        .setPrimaryNavigationFragment(selectedFragment)
                        .apply {
                            // Detach all other Fragments
                            graphIdToTagMap.forEach { _, fragmentTagIter ->
                                if (fragmentTagIter != newlySelectedItemTag) {
                                    detach(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(firstFragmentTag)!!)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .addToBackStack(firstFragmentTag)
                        .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                        .commit()
                }
                selectedItemTag = newlySelectedItemTag
                isOnFirstFragment = selectedItemTag == firstFragmentTag
                selectedNavController.value = selectedFragment.navController
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
        }
    }

    // Optional: on item reselected, pop back stack to the destination of the graph
    setupItemReselected(graphIdToTagMap, fragmentManager)

    // Handle deep link
    setupDeepLinks(navGraphIds, fragmentManager, containerId, intent)

    // Finally, ensure that we update our BottomNavigationView when the back stack changes
    fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
        if (!isOnFirstFragment && !fragmentManager.isOnBackStack(firstFragmentTag)) {
            this.selectedItemId = firstFragmentGraphId
        }

        // Reset the graph if the currentDestination is not valid (happens when the back
        // stack is popped after using the back button).
        selectedNavController.value?.let { controller ->
            if (controller.currentDestination == null) {
                controller.navigate(controller.graph.id)
            }
        }
    }
    return selectedNavController
}

private fun BottomNavigationView.setupDeepLinks(
    navGraphIds: List<Int>,
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    containerId: Int,
    intent: Intent
) {
    navGraphIds.forEachIndexed { index, navGraphId ->
        val fragmentTag = getFragmentTag(index)

        // Find or create the Navigation host fragment
        val navHostFragment = obtainNavHostFragment(
            fragmentManager,
            fragmentTag,
            navGraphId,
            containerId
        )
        // Handle Intent
        if (navHostFragment.navController.handleDeepLink(intent)
                && selectedItemId != navHostFragment.navController.graph.id) {
            this.selectedItemId = navHostFragment.navController.graph.id
        }
    }
}

private fun BottomNavigationView.setupItemReselected(
    graphIdToTagMap: SparseArray<String>,
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager
) {
    setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener { item ->
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(Intent(SELECTED_RESELETED_ITEM).apply {
            putExtra("item", item.itemId)
        })
        val newlySelectedItemTag = graphIdToTagMap[item.itemId]
        val selectedFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(newlySelectedItemTag)
            as NavHostFragment
        val navController = selectedFragment.navController
        // Pop the back stack to the start destination of the current navController graph
        navController.popBackStack(
            navController.graph.startDestination, false
        )
    }
}

private fun detachNavHostFragment(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    navHostFragment: NavHostFragment
) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .detach(navHostFragment)
        .commitNow()
}

private fun attachNavHostFragment(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    navHostFragment: NavHostFragment,
    isPrimaryNavFragment: Boolean
) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .attach(navHostFragment)
        .apply {
            if (isPrimaryNavFragment) {
                setPrimaryNavigationFragment(navHostFragment)
            }
        }
        .commitNow()

}

private fun obtainNavHostFragment(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    fragmentTag: String,
    navGraphId: Int,
    containerId: Int
): NavHostFragment {
    // If the Nav Host fragment exists, return it
    val existingFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag) as NavHostFragment?
    existingFragment?.let { return it }

    // Otherwise, create it and return it.
    val navHostFragment = NavHostFragment.create(navGraphId)
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .add(containerId, navHostFragment, fragmentTag)
        .commitNow()
    return navHostFragment
}

private fun FragmentManager.isOnBackStack(backStackName: String): Boolean {
    val backStackCount = backStackEntryCount
    for (index in 0 until backStackCount) {
        if (getBackStackEntryAt(index).name == backStackName) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

private fun getFragmentTag(index: Int) = "bottomNavigation#$index"
```

Can anyone please help, how I can use my own back icon.

Answer (score 1):

The developers of the navigation component didn't provide a way to change the icon.

But this is possible by next way:

1. Create a package in your project: "androidx.navigation.ui"
2. Create ModifiedAbstractAppBarOnDestinationChangedListener:

```js
package androidx.navigation.ui;

import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.StringRes;
import androidx.appcompat.graphics.drawable.DrawerArrowDrawable;
import androidx.customview.widget.Openable;
import androidx.navigation.FloatingWindow;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.NavDestination;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * The abstract OnDestinationChangedListener for keeping any type of app bar updated.
 * This handles both updating the title and updating the Up Indicator, transitioning between
 * the drawer icon and up arrow as needed.
 * @hide
 */
public abstract class ModifiedAbstractAppBarOnDestinationChangedListener
        implements NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final Set<Integer> mTopLevelDestinations;
    @Nullable
    private final WeakReference<Openable> mOpenableLayoutWeakReference;
    private DrawerArrowDrawable mArrowDrawable;
    private ValueAnimator mAnimator;

    ModifiedAbstractAppBarOnDestinationChangedListener(@NonNull Context context,
                                                       @NonNull AppBarConfiguration configuration) {
        mContext = context;
        mTopLevelDestinations = configuration.getTopLevelDestinations();
        Openable openableLayout = configuration.getOpenableLayout();
        if (openableLayout != null) {
            mOpenableLayoutWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(openableLayout);
        } else {
            mOpenableLayoutWeakReference = null;
        }
    }

    protected abstract void setTitle(CharSequence title);

    protected abstract void setNavigationIcon(Drawable icon, @StringRes int contentDescription, int destinationId);

    @Override
    public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller,
                                     @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
        if (destination instanceof FloatingWindow) {
            return;
        }
        Openable openableLayout = mOpenableLayoutWeakReference != null
                ? mOpenableLayoutWeakReference.get()
                : null;
        if (mOpenableLayoutWeakReference != null && openableLayout == null) {
            controller.removeOnDestinationChangedListener(this);
            return;
        }
        int id = destination.getId();
        CharSequence label = destination.getLabel();
        if (label != null) {
            // Fill in the data pattern with the args to build a valid URI
            StringBuffer title = new StringBuffer();
            Pattern fillInPattern = Pattern.compile("\\{(.+?)\\}");
            Matcher matcher = fillInPattern.matcher(label);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                String argName = matcher.group(1);
                if (arguments != null && arguments.containsKey(argName)) {
                    matcher.appendReplacement(title, "");
                    //noinspection ConstantConditions
                    title.append(arguments.get(argName).toString());
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not find " + argName + " in "
                            + arguments + " to fill label " + label);
                }
            }
            matcher.appendTail(title);
            setTitle(title);
        }
        boolean isTopLevelDestination = NavigationUI.matchDestinations(destination,
                mTopLevelDestinations);
        if (openableLayout == null && isTopLevelDestination) {
            setNavigationIcon(null, 0, id);
        } else {
            setActionBarUpIndicator(openableLayout != null && isTopLevelDestination, id);
        }
    }

    private void setActionBarUpIndicator(boolean showAsDrawerIndicator, int destinationId) {
        boolean animate = true;
        if (mArrowDrawable == null) {
            mArrowDrawable = new DrawerArrowDrawable(mContext);
            // We're setting the initial state, so skip the animation
            animate = false;
        }
        setNavigationIcon(mArrowDrawable, showAsDrawerIndicator
                ? R.string.nav_app_bar_open_drawer_description
                : R.string.nav_app_bar_navigate_up_description,
                destinationId);
        float endValue = showAsDrawerIndicator ? 0f : 1f;
        if (animate) {
            float startValue = mArrowDrawable.getProgress();
            if (mAnimator != null) {
                mAnimator.cancel();
            }
            mAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mArrowDrawable, "progress",
                    startValue, endValue);
            mAnimator.start();
        } else {
            mArrowDrawable.setProgress(endValue);
        }
    }
}
```

3. Create ModifiedToolbarOnDestinationChangedListener and add ability to change or replace the drawable icon with getModifiedIcon(drawable, destinationId) method:

```js
package androidx.navigation.ui;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.StringRes;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.NavDestination;
import androidx.transition.TransitionManager;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

/**
 * The OnDestinationChangedListener specifically for keeping a Toolbar updated.
 * This handles both updating the title and updating the Up Indicator, transitioning between
 * the drawer icon and up arrow as needed.
 * @hide
 */
public class ModifiedToolbarOnDestinationChangedListener extends
        ModifiedAbstractAppBarOnDestinationChangedListener {
    private final WeakReference<Toolbar> mToolbarWeakReference;

    public ModifiedToolbarOnDestinationChangedListener(
            @NonNull Toolbar toolbar, @NonNull AppBarConfiguration configuration) {
        super(toolbar.getContext(), configuration);
        mToolbarWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller,
                                     @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
        Toolbar toolbar = mToolbarWeakReference.get();
        if (toolbar == null) {
            controller.removeOnDestinationChangedListener(this);
            return;
        }
        super.onDestinationChanged(controller, destination, arguments);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mToolbarWeakReference.get().setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setNavigationIcon(Drawable icon, @StringRes int contentDescription, int destinationId) {
        Toolbar toolbar = mToolbarWeakReference.get();
        if (toolbar != null) {
            Drawable modifiedIcon = getModifiedIcon(icon, destinationId);
            boolean useTransition = modifiedIcon == null && toolbar.getNavigationIcon() != null;
            toolbar.setNavigationIcon(modifiedIcon);
            toolbar.setNavigationContentDescription(contentDescription);
            if (useTransition) {
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(toolbar);
            }
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    protected Drawable getModifiedIcon(@Nullable Drawable drawable, int destinationId) {
       return drawable;
    }

}
```

3. Setup the Navigation component with modified classes and change the drawable icon in depend on destinationId:

```js
    fun setupWithNavController(toolbar: Toolbar, navController: NavController, configuration: AppBarConfiguration) {
        val listener = object : ModifiedToolbarOnDestinationChangedListener(toolbar, configuration) {
            override fun getModifiedIcon(drawable: Drawable?, destinationId: Int): Drawable? {
                // Return the drawable in depend on destinationId
                if (drawable is DrawerArrowDrawable){
                    drawable.color = Icon.getInstance().iconsColor
                }
                return drawable
            }
        }
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(listener)
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, configuration) }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Navigation-Component and you have toolbar set on activity_main.xml then this might help you out. To show a customised back-icon you can do the following in each fragment.

```
private fun setUpToolbar() {
    (requireActivity() as MainActivity).findViewById<MaterialToolbar>(R.id.toolbar).apply {
        setNavigationIcon(YOUR_AWSOME_BACK_ICON)
    }
}
```

### Explanation

1. Get the reference of the MainActivity
2. Access the toolbar in the Fragment (In my case it
   is material toolbar)
3. Simply change the toolbar icon you want to show.